# C++ fstream - problems reading only certain variable types

Tags: c++, fstream

I am using fstream to read a notepad file containing numerical data. I am using dynamic memory allocation and the data is type float. 
However there is rouge data in form of characters in my file - how would I write code that searches for and ignores the characters in the file, and only reads in the numbers?

I am assuming I will need to use either ignore or peek?

```
fstream myfile("data1");
myfile.ignore ();


or myfile.peek ();
```

But am a bit unsure. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you in a propper way...

Comment: I haven't written much yet - don't know where to start with it?

Comment: Can you show us how the data looks like? A piece of the  input file. Is it ASCII, binary?

Comment: Show sample of your data file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Zvi7NVt2

Comment: that is the skeleton code... then  my file is http://pastebin.com/5qtFmQKZ

Comment: I don't want it written for me - just point me in the right direction - bit of a novice!

Comment: does your data contain things like `1.0e+23bcd` ? If so, it's really ambiguous, and one can't generally tell if it should be `1.0e+2 3bcd` or `1.0e+23 bcd`. If there are properly separated with delimiters like whitespaces, then @Olaf's answer does it.

Comment: Oh no, the only input it needs to run with is what I have shown above - so all words and numbers are separated by new lines

Answer (score 2):

If it has always this format, the words and numbers are separated by whitespace, you can simply read it one string at a time and let a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) do the parsing. When this fails, you know it is not a number

```
std::string word;
while (myfile >> word) {
    std::istringstream is(word);
    double d;
    if (is >> d) {
        // found a number
        std::cout << d << '\n';
    } else {
        // something's wrong
        std::cerr << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

*Update:*

Due to popular demand: a `stringstream` works like any other stream (`std::cin`, `std::cout` or `std::fstream`). The main difference is that a stringstream operates on strings. This means input comes from a string instead of a file or standard input, or output goes to a string, much like it goes to standard output or a file.

Comment: Okay, since i am a complete novice - Any chance you can explain what the term istringstream and string does (or are they just variable types?)? Sorry am really new at this!

Comment: Well, this is what books are for ;-) Please see updated answer and [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1741542), of course.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing input is like this typically requires that you extract the tokens into a string and
test the content of your string against your parsing requirements. For example, when you extract into the string, you can then run a function which inserts it into a `std::stringstream`, then extract into the data type you're testing against, and see if it succeeds.

Another option is to check if the string is *not* a certain string, and convert back to the desired data type if so:

```
while (f >> str)
{
    if (f != "badInput")
    {
        // convert to double and add to array 
    }
}
```

Fortunately you can use the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) facilities to avoid having to do most of the work yourself. Here's an example similar to yours:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f("test.txt");
    std::string token;

    boost::regex floatingPoint("((\\+|-)?[0-9]+)?(\\.)?([0-9]+)");

    while (f >> token)
    {
        if (boost::regex_match(token, floatingPoint))
        {
            // convert to double using lexical_cast<> and add to array
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everybody - But all this seems a bit advanced for someone of my poor capability! We have been suggested to use the following - but am unsure how you would do this to distinguish between words and numbers:

```
fstream myfile("data1");
myfile.eof ();
myfile.good ();
myfile.fail ();
myfile.clear ();
myfile.ignore ();
myfile.close ();
myfile.peek ();
```